# Scraping/extracting data using mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Using Mechanize, I would like to scrape information on this website => http://www.africanbookscollective.com

This is the information I would like to gather:

- All Books listed under the category Fiction

Under this category, I want:

1. Author name
2. Book Title
3. isbn number
4. Publisher
5. Country

I have figured out that this url => 
http://www.africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-literature/fiction
gives me the information I want.

The is my current code:

```
require 'awesome_print'
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-literature/fiction')
a = page.links.each do |link|
  puts link.text
end

ap a
```

This is my first time using mechanize and as such I am not exactly sure how it differs from Nokogiri. The main reason I am using it in this particular case is because I need to extract information across 38 pages (the complete list of **Books tagged Fiction**).

**ISSUES:**

1. I am getting a really really long output from mechanize that includes links I don't need.
2. The information I need is not in a div class - it is in a a dl class and I have tried googling for how to select that a dl class but have not had any luck so far.
3. Each time I have performed a regex operation to remove the links I do not war, i get an empty array back

Can someone, anyone, please help me think of a new way to approach this problem? I really would appreciate feedback.

PS: Here is an image that might shed some more light

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrape4me.com to get the raw output for further process in your project(mechanize) Don't know mechanize but maybe this can help, good luck